# How to display Label and Value in h:outputText

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I want to display datacenter id and datacenter Name in this case 1000 and DC1.

I made this complex JSF code but it turns out that I cannot display the id as Value and Datacenter name as label. Something like this:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{ZoneProfileTabGeneralController.listDatacenters}" var="datacenters" itemValue="#{datacenters.datacenterid}" itemLabel="#{datacenters.datacentername} - #{datacenters.datacenterid}" />
```

This is the test that I made.

```
<h:outputText value="#{ZoneProfileTabGeneralController.DatacenterNameId(ud.datacenterId)} - #{ud.datacenterId}"
```

Is there any way to display the id as hidden value and the name as label. But when I submit the JSF page to send back only the datacenter id?

***EDIT***

```
<tr>
    <td>Datacenter ID</td>
    <td>
        <h:outputText value="#{ud.datacenterId}"
                      rendered="#{not ZoneProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{ud.datacenterId}" label="#{ZoneProfileTabGeneralController.DatacenterNameId(ud.datacenterId)} - #{ud.datacenterId}" rendered="#{ZoneProfileTabGeneralController.editable}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{ZoneProfileTabGeneralController.listDatacenters}" var="datacenters" itemValue="#{datacenters.datacenterid}" itemLabel="#{datacenters.datacentername} - #{datacenters.datacenterid}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: "it turns out that I cannot display the id as Value and Datacenter name as label": how are you sure of that? what error do you get? I'm not sure what the test you made with `h:outputText` is testing. Please, try to be more clear stating the behavior you were expecting, and the behavior you are getting.

Comment: The `<f:selectItems>` code looks legit. What exactly is your problem? The `<h:outputText>` code looks indeed suspiciously wrong. At least, it doesn't comply standard naming conventions.

Comment: I pasted the complete code. The problem is how I can display the name and the value but store only the id into the object.

Comment: As said, the `<f:selectItems>` code looks legit. The item value represents only the ID. The item label represents the name and ID, separated by hyphen. You need to more clearly describe the concrete problem.